# Visual Studio SQL database, an error occurred while the batch was being executed (Msg 1785)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I have created the following table in service based database (Microsoft SQL) of my MS visual studio project:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[users] (
    [phone_number]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [name]     VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [picture]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [password] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [PK_users] PRIMARY KEY ([phone_number])
);
```

and after that when I try adding the following table I am getting the error:

> an error occurred while the batch was being executed

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[location] (
    [location_id] INT  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    [sender]      VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [reciever]    VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [latitude]    FLOAT (53)   NOT NULL,
    [longitude]   FLOAT (53)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_1] FOREIGN KEY ([sender]) REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([phone_number]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_2] FOREIGN KEY ([reciever]) REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([phone_number]) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

There appears no warnings while creating update script and there is also no data already present in the database. I tried recreating everything from scratch but the error persists. What am I possibly doing wrong?

**EDIT :** The error disappears if I remove both "ON DELETE CASCADE" and "ON UPDATE CASCADE" from any one of the foreign key constraints, removing in any other combination doesn't helps. what's wrong with those constraints?

Comment: Number is really bad column name...

Comment: So both sender and receiver are FK for the number column? Do you mean instead name?

Comment: @jarlh: sorry number is intended to be used for storing phone number.

Comment: @Steve: no I mean exactly as I am using it, meaning one phone number can be a sender and the other one can be a receiver and their sending relationship or record is saved in the location table.

Comment: Then remove the ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE

Comment: Are those constraints maybe stepping on eachother?

Comment: @Steve : that means I will have to manually manage the deletion and updation of records in the users table. I would like it to be auto handled, why is it causing a problem?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321843

Comment: @Steve: actually i guess you are getting it wrong, sender and receiver would be two distinct but separate fields; meaning a phone number 123-123-1234 is the sender and 123-123-1235 is the receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this error executing your code in SSMS.  I did a quick search and there is plenty of info on the topic for you to research.

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_2' on table 'location' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.
>   Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other
>   FOREIGN KEY constraints. Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 2 Could not
>   create constraint or index. See previous errors.

EDIT based on chat:

I think that based on your desire to delete the location it would be best if you did just that. Keep the FK's for integrity and maybe create a stored procedure to delete a user

1. Begin transaction
2. Delete from locations where sender = userid or reciever = userid (or phone_number if you stick with that PK)
3. Delete from user table
4. Commit transaction

Comment: I appreciate your concern, can you please elaborate a bit more that in which scenario it would cause a cycle?

Comment: I have not read much into it but it seems to me that since both foreign keys are pointing to the same field in the same table there could be conflict.  For example if you delete a user the location record will be deleted.  If you specify it twice two attempts will be made to delete the same record(s).  Usually a FK points to a primary key and is only referenced once.  The intent of your design, linking to phone number, is not clear to me.

Comment: I get your point, then what is the best schema to maintain say sending of messages from phone_number_1 to phone_number_2 so they could be auto updated or deleted when any of the two is deleted or updated in the parent table.

Comment: Personally I would not have sender and receiver fields populated with phone numbers.  They would just be integers related to an ID on the user table.  You would only need the constraint on one of the foreign keys, deleting the user would delete the location.

Comment: Even if I use an int id and use it as FK instead of phone_number then update cascade wont be required but still I would required on delete cascade. And if I use on delete cascade on one of the foreign keys say sender then if the receiver is removed from the user table then what?

Comment: Good point, I was not thinking it all the way through.  I would likely build an associative entity if I was building the database.  You have an accepted answer though so I wont get into it.

Comment: Yeah i do have an accepted answer but there are still some "if and buts" in that answer. I can't implement triggers and foreign keys on the same primary key at the same time, look at my comment at the accepted answer.
In short I am still open to suggestion, I kind of liked your idea of an int used as primary key, it at least reduced my problem to half.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114267/discussion-between-joe-c-and-saif-ullah).

Answer (score 2):

Given the documentation on MSDN about [Msg 1785](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321843)

> You receive this error message because in SQL Server, a table cannot
>   appear more than one time in a list of all the cascading referential
>   actions that are started by either a DELETE or an UPDATE statement.
>   For example, the tree of cascading referential actions must only have
>   one path to a particular table on the cascading referential actions
>   tree.

and their stated workaround

> You can enforce referential integrity in several ways. Declarative
>   Referential Integrity (DRI) is the most basic way, but it is also the
>   least flexible way. If you need more flexibility, but you still want a
>   high degree of integrity, you can use triggers instead

We could choose to avoid this problem creating a TRIGGER in this way

```
ALTER  TRIGGER [dbo].[CascadeDeleteNumber]
   ON  [dbo].[users]
   INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DELETE FROM location WHERE Sender = (select phone_number from deleted)
    DELETE FROM location WHERE Reciever = (select phone_number from deleted)
    DELETE FROM users WHERE phone_number = (select phone_number from deleted)

END
```

The DELETE trigger is an INSTEAD OF because the AFTER trigger is never executed blocked by the check on the referential integrity. The INSTEAD OF allows us to delete first the records in the location table and then the record in the users table leaving the referential integrity happy

For the UPDATE we could use another TRIGGER but it is more tricky.
I haven't find a way to correctly update the phone_number without breaking the referential integrity and thus I have managed to change the phone_number temporarily removing the referential integrity, updating the required record and then reinstatiate the referential integrity.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[CascadeUpdateNumber]
   ON  [dbo].[users]
   INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @old_num nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @new_num nvarchar(50)
    DECLARE @new_name varchar(50)
    DECLARE @new_img varchar(50)
    DECLARE @new_pwd varchar(50)
    SELECT @old_num = phone_number FROM deleted
    SELECT @new_num = phone_number, @new_name = name, @new_img = picture,
           @new_pwd = password FROM inserted


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_1]
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_2]

    UPDATE location SET sender = @new_num WHERE sender = @old_num
    UPDATE location SET reciever = @new_num WHERE reciever = @old_num
    UPDATE users SET phone_number = @new_num, name = @new_name, 
                 picture=@new_img, password=@new_pwd 
                 WHERE phone_number = @old_num

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location]  WITH CHECK 
       ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_3] FOREIGN KEY([sender])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([phone_number])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location]  WITH CHECK 
       ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_4] FOREIGN KEY([reciever])
            REFERENCES [dbo].[users] ([phone_number])

END
```

Sincerily I don't know if this approach is safe from a point of view of concurrent updates on the table.

Comment: Aha! I interpreted the question as the reversed cascade (trigger on _locations_ cascade to _users_). That would be a bit more messy ;)

Comment: @Steve: If I use trigger then I'll have to remove foreign key constraints, as after adding trigger, when I try to remove or update the primary key in the parent table it shows [this](http://imgur.com/nKpQbIY)  error. I don't want to remove the foreign key constraints as it would cause data inconsistency. How can I ensure data consistency via triggers?

Comment: I see, need to change the triggers to INSTEAD OF. The update part is tricky and I am not sure if this is safe in a very high concurrency scenarios, but it works also with the references. Updating